# Concatenate DateTime (yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff) to a string in a dynamic sql query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have below DateTime value obtained using T-SQL `GetDate()` function and I am trying to concatenate it to a dynamic SQL query.

> 2020-02-25 11:35:29.240

and I am trying to concatenate to a WHERE clause like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.MyProc
   @paramList varchar(200)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @sqlCommand nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @Now DATETIME = Getdate() 

-- Do some stuff

SET @sqlCommand ='SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE DeptId IN (' + @paramList + ') AND ''' + @Now + ''' <= datetimeField'

EXECUTE sp_executesql @sqlCommand

END
```

but it does not work.

Note: @paramList is a sp parameter that comes from C# .NET.

Comment: Where is the column name in where clause??

Comment: What does "It does not work" actually mean? Is it throwing an error? If so what is the error? Is it returning the wrong results? If so what are the results?

Comment: Why set the value of `GETDATE()` to a variable? Why not just use `GETDATE()` in the "dynamic" statement? And why a dynamic statement, when there's nothing dynamic about it. Feels like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info).

Comment: What's the point of this query? The only thing it can do is introduce bugs. Just execute the command directly, including any parameters if they are still needed

Comment: Or `current_timestamp` if you want to be ANSI compliant.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE  @Now + <= datetimeField` works as-is. There's no reason to go through a string. Are you trying to create a query with different filter clauses perhaps?

Comment: @Larnu sorry in the where clause there are variables (sp parameters) concatenated and I omitted in this example to only focus in the datetime field.

Comment: But parameters aren't dynamic, so that doesn't answer my question. You should never be doing things like `'...WHERE Col1 = ''' + @Col1 + ''' AND Col2 = ''' + @Col2;` There's nothing dynamic about that, so just use a non-dynamic query and do `WHERE Col1 = @Col1 AND Col2 = @Col2;`

Comment: Sorry I have updated my post.

Comment: The relevant question here remains, What does "It does not work" actually mean?, as @DaleK asked at the outset. I'd bet the error is actually tied to `lstDeptId` and not the date value at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use use `sp_executesql` with parameter:

```
SET @sqlCommand ='SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE @now <= datetimeField'    

EXECUTE sp_executesql @sqlCommand, N'@now datetime', @Now = @Now
```

However, simple query will do what you want :

```
DECLARE @Now DATETIME = GETDATE() 

SELECT * 
FROM MyTable 
WHERE datetimeField <= @Now;
```

Comment: Might want to mention the OP needs to use `Where @Now <=` rather than `WHERE ''' + @Now + '''...`